# Excel vlookup returning same value for all records

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using `VLOOKUP` to pick values from `Sheet2`

Sheet1:

[image: sheet1]

Sheet 2:

[image: Sheet 2]

My `VLOOKUP` formula in `C2:C5` of `Sheet1`:

`=VLOOKUP($A2&"|"&$B2,CHOOSE({1,2},Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4&"|"&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$4),2,FALSE)`

My problem is that values are same for all records.

Below are the values I see when I do F9.

[image: values]

Why are the same values returned?

Comment: If you use Ctrl+Shift+Enter, and then drag down - does it work ? i.e. as an array formula

Answer (score 0):

I can get lookup data from column 3 on sheet 2 using:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A1:C4,3)
```

[image]

Comment: Using one column as lookup value works, but I have to use 2 columns(A,B) together to get the values from the other sheet.

Comment: Maybe set you data as fixed ranges so you are doing a VLOOKUP inside a fixed range? Or you could try ensuring that the absolute value signs ($) maintain your data i.e. =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$4,3). Finally if that does not work then I find sometimes turning off and on auto calculate can fix any "bug" or you should try INDEX match? Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This might also be working

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$12;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($A$9:$A$12)/(A2&B2=$A$9:$A$12&$B$9:$B$12);1))
```

just adapt the ranges to your needs

[image]